# Difference between process contention scope and system contention scope

Tags: operating-systems

According to my understanding the difference between them is that in process contention scope there is a contention within the process for mapping user threads to kernel threads and for system contention scope there is a contention within the system for what certain kernel thread to run on the processor. First of all is my explanation right ? Secondly , these two schemes are used for thread scheduling do we use them in parallel in any Multi threading Model ( one to one , many to many , etc. ) ( I mean for the user level part we use the PCS and for the kernel level we use SCS. This is done for every multi-threading model ) if no, then why ?